# ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and binary targets

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I want to apply `KerasCLassifier` to solve multi-class classification problem. The value of `y` is one-hot-encoded, e.g.:

```
0 1 0
1 0 0
1 0 0
```

This is my code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

# Function to create model, required for KerasClassifier
def create_model(optimizer='rmsprop', init='glorot_uniform'):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(2048, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], kernel_initializer=init, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(512, kernel_initializer=init, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(y_train_onehot.shape[1], kernel_initializer=init, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# create model
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, class_weight="balanced", verbose=2)

# grid search epochs, batch size and optimizer
optimizers = ['rmsprop', 'adam']
epochs = [10, 50]
batches = [5, 10, 20]
init = ['glorot_uniform', 'normal', 'uniform']

param_grid = dict(optimizer=optimizers, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batches, init=init)
grid = model_selection.GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='accuracy')

grid_result = grid.fit(X_train], y_train_onehot)
```

When I run the last line of code, it throws the following error after 10 epochs:

> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py
>   in accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize, sample_weight)
>       174 
>       175     # Compute accuracy for each possible representation
>   --> 176     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
>       177     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
>       178     if y_type.startswith('multilabel'):
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py
>   in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
>        79     if len(y_type) > 1:
>        80         raise ValueError("Classification metrics can't handle a mix of {0} "
>   ---> 81                          "and {1} targets".format(type_true, type_pred))
>        82 
>        83     # We can't have more than one value on y_type => The set is no more needed
>
> ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of
>   multilabel-indicator and binary targets

When I write `categorical_accuracy` or `balanced_accuracy` instead of `accuracy`, I cannot compile a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

N = 100
X_train = np.random.rand(N, 4)
Y_train = np.random.choice([0,1,2], N, p=[.5, .3, .2])

# Function to create model, required for KerasClassifier
def create_model(optimizer='rmsprop', init='glorot_uniform'):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(2048, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], kernel_initializer=init, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(512, kernel_initializer=init, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(len(np.unique(Y_train)), kernel_initializer=init, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
    return model

# create model
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, class_weight="balanced", verbose=2)

# grid search epochs, batch size and optimizer
optimizers = ['rmsprop', 'adam']
epochs = [10, 50]
batches = [5, 10, 20]
init = ['glorot_uniform', 'normal', 'uniform']

param_grid = dict(optimizer=optimizers, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batches, init=init)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='accuracy')

grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

PS please pay attention at the usage of `sparse_categorical_*` loss function and metrics.

Comment: Thank you, @MaxU. I have another issue with this task. If you have time to check, please visit this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54537304/runtimeerror-cannot-clone-object-keras-wrappers-scikit-learn-kerasclassifier-ob